# webpack ¿Como crear mi propia platilla para renombrar los bundles o chunks?

Tags: webpack

Por ahí leí que se puede crear una plantilla personalizada, al igual que `[hash]`, `[chunkhash]`, `[contenthash]`, etc. Lo cual cuando es usada retorna algo así: `chunk.89s7a29.js`

Y pense que se podía usar este plugin nativo de webpack [TemplatedPathPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/TemplatedPathPlugin.js) pero al usarlo de esta forma:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.TemplatedPathPlugin({
    algo: (path, data) => {
      return data.name + '.' + customHash;
    }
  })
],
output: {
  filename: '[algo].js'
}
```

Pero en la consola me dice que `TemplatedPathPlugin` no es un constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo logre instalando este paquete para webpack

```sh
npm i @wordpress/custom-templated-path-webpack-plugin
```